# Error in 2 files when checking disk

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1

I used the media creating tool from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media) to delete all my partitions and install Windows on my computer.

When I boot from an Ubuntu LiveUSB and use the option to check disk for errors, it says that there are errors in 2 files.
It does not give any details about what files or what errors.

I checked the hash of the iso before installing it onto my USB drive and it was correct. I used the [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to install the iso onto my USB.

When I use the option to try Ubuntu before installing it and use GParted, I get [this](http://imgur.com/PmBCupT,B1cNVe9) error.
When I click cancel, it has three drives that it detects, two of them are the 60GB storage drives that make up my RAID system, and the other is my Ubuntu USB.

It does not detect the virtual drive that my RAID system creates.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I haven't actually performed this operation, but it looks like [someone here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181662#post_12971920) may have been enable to solve the problem: "I was able to get past the error message by disabling RAID and then proceeding with the installation. However, neither Windows nor Ubuntu would boot after restarting, so I reenabled RAID. After this, Windows would boot but not Ubuntu. I was able to successfully boot into Ubuntu after disabling Secure Boot. Hope this helps someone else."

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I recorded the checking process with my phone and found that `./boot/grub/loopback.cfg` and `./boot/grub/grub.cfg` are the files that mismatch.  This happens with Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit desktop.